# Dynamic View Pager in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to create pages dynamically using view pager in android.Each page having four buttons. When I click the button1 in Page1 it gives log as One and when I press the button1 at page2 it also gives One as output. But when I press the button1 at page2 I need log as five.

Because the buttons may increase dynamically, each button having different functionality.Based on the buttons count, the page need to create itself.

Please give any solutions.Thanks in advance.

Comment: thank you for immediate response. In your example only textview should repeat every page, But in my case button should repeat with various functionality.In each page I have four buttons and each button need to have different id. How to do this,Please give me some suggestions.